# Socket.io memory leak

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is my full node.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http    = require("http"),
    app     = express(),
    server  = http.createServer(app),
    sio     = require('socket.io'),
    io      = null;

server.listen(3000, "localhost");
io = sio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.emit('access', "connected");
});
```

When I check the node.exe process (I'm on localhost windows), every time a user connects, the memory usage increases but every time a user disconnects, the memory usage doesn't decrease. Is something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I can also be the redisClient that you use that keeps the reference.

Either try with another redis Client or try setting the `redisClient = null;` and see if that changes something.

It can also be something else in your code.

You can also try the Node Inspector which run in the Chrome developer tools where you can see the different object that are in memory.

Comment: Just tried setting it to null but it makes no difference. What do you mean the redisClient that I use keeps the reference? I create a new redisClient everytime a user connects.

Comment: It could be the library that leaks memory and not your code

Comment: I'm just using the standard redis module

Comment: Try taking a heap dump with the node inspector and post it here.

Comment: Check my new code, I basically removed everything besides the socket.io connection but memory usage is still the same